# Need Help to Solve 2 Simultaneous ODEs

Tags: ode, simultaneous

I have very little experience with MATLAB and am trying to write code for solving the 2 equations below.  Can someone provide me some guidance on who to solve these equations?

```
DKS=1.96*10^-9;
DLS=1.03*10^-9;
JT = 0.000506707;
JK = 0.000268163;
CKA=125;
CKB=125;
% x = 0 - 0.0005 m (independent variable)
% At x = 0,K = L = 125 moles/m^3 

%Unknowns are K and L

ODE1 = -DKS*diff(CKB,x)*(2*CKB+CLB)/(CKB+CLB)-DKS*CKB/(CKB+CLB)*diff(CLB,x)-JK == 0;
ODE2 = -DLS*diff(CLB,x)*(CKB+2CLB)/(CKB+CLB)+DLS*CLB/(CKB+CLB)*diff(CKB,2)+JT-JK == 0;
```

I tried generating code using ODE45, but I am not experienced enough to know how to use it.

Comment: So CKB and CLB are the dependent variables and not constants, the system is second order in CKB and first order in CLB, making for a 3-dimensional state vector. There are functions in Matlab that translate symbolic formulations of a system into an ODE function that can be passed to the solver, but in this case it is simple to find explicit equations for the leading-order derivatives.